# Como detectar 3 números iguais?

Tags: php

Tenho um ciclo `For` que tem dois `mt_rand`, um de números aleatórios e outro `mt_rand` de números que são designados como prêmios.

O que pretendo agora é verificar quando sai 3 números iguais, efetuar a soma dos valores que saíram nesse `mt_rand` dos 3 números e retornar numa variável com a soma total desses valores.

**PHP**

```
for ($i = 0; $i<9; $i++){
    $numeros = mt_rand(1,9);
    $premio = mt_rand(1,20);
    echo "valor" . ($i + 1) . "=$numeros&premio" . ($i + 1) . "=$premio&";
}
```

Comment: Não está claro o suficiente essa pergunta para te ajudarmos. Pode nos dar um exemplo de como você quer que aconteça ?

Comment: Isto e um projecto tipo raspadinha no flash eu tenho 9 quadrados e tenho um botao comprar a raspadinha quando clico em comprar ele vai ao php e no ciclo for gera os numeros da sorte e os respectivos premios que vao aparecer nas caixas quero que quando sair 3 numeros iguais ele some os  valores dos premios que sairem nesses 3 numeoros iguais e retorne numa variavel total o valor para mostrar no flash

Comment: normalmente em outras linguagens, criamos uma lista, e cada número aleatório jogamos na lista, assim fica fácil de verificar se o número já existe na lista em C# seria algo assim: if(!listRnd[].Contem(novoRnd))

Comment: Faça uma versão do seu algoritmo em linguagem natural, passo a passo, que coloco minha sugestão da versão em PHP. Será um prazer ajudar!

Comment: Uma versão em linguagem natural como assim ?

Comment: Como o @Dorathoto disse, em linguas como C# e Java tem bibliotecas que fica fácil resolver esse problema. Você joga todos os números numa lista, e usa, usando o Java como exemplo: Collections.frequency(lista, número) retorna a frequencia, List.contains(objeto) retorna boolean etc..

Se eu não me engano no PHP tem algo assim também, mas não manjo muito das bibliotecas dessa.

Comment: Sim mas no php tambem da para fazer penso eu

Comment: Os três números precisam ser igual naquele conjunto exemplo, 5,5,5 (válido), 5,5,5,8 (possível inválido). Ou seja a cada grupo de três, todos devem ser iguais.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta carece de informações mais precisas para demonstrar uma solução concisa. Mas independente disso, baseado no que postou:

```
$premio_soma = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i<9; $i++) {
    $n = mt_rand(1, 9);
    $premio[$n][] = mt_rand(1, 20);
    if (isset($numeros[$n])) {
        $numeros[$n]++;
        // encontrou 3 ocorrências do mesmo número
        if ($numeros[$n] == 3) {
            // teste, exibe os 3 números a somar
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($premio[$n]); echo '</pre>'; //exit;
            // some os 3 numeros
            $premio_soma = array_sum($premio[$n]);
            // interrompe o laço de repetição
            break;
        }
    } else {
        $numeros[$n] = 1;
    }
}

echo 'premio: '.$premio_soma;
```

É possível otimizar e/ou criar uma lógica melhor. Apenas fiz de um jeito seguindo a lógica do que postou baseado na "estrutura" do código original.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de resolver é juntar cada grupo de três e verificar se todos são iguais, note o valor inicial de `$i` passou de zero para um, para identificar os multiplos de três:

```
$sorteados = array();
for($i = 1; $i<10; $i++){
    $numero = mt_rand(1,9);
    $premio = mt_rand(1,20);
    $sorteados[] = $numero;

    if($i % 3 === 0){
        if($sorteados[0] == $sorteados[1] && $sorteados[1] == $sorteados[2]){
            printf('Iguais: %s - %s - %s | prêmio: %s <br>', $sorteados[0], $sorteados[1], $sorteados[2], array_sum($sorteados));
        }else{
            printf('Sorteados: %s - %s - %s | prêmio: %s  <br>', $sorteados[0], $sorteados[1], $sorteados[2], $premio);
        }
        $sorteados = array();
    }
}
```

Possível saida:

```
Iguais: 8 - 8 - 8    | prêmio: 24
Sorteados: 8 - 1 - 1 | prêmio: 17
Sorteados: 4 - 7 - 8 | prêmio: 12
```